# Own dropdown in Bootstrap 3: stopPropagation, but input field doesn't recognize spacebar input

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I program my own dropdown content in a dropdown-menu. First I had to stop closing the dropdown-menu when there was a click in the dropdown with:

```
$('.dropdown-menu input, .dropdown-menu label, .dropdown-menu button').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Now the input fields in my own dropdown-menu don't accept spacebar input. What have I forgotten?

Answer (score 1):

I removed the

```
role="menu"
```

now I have I have my full own controll to the dropdown-menu.

Thanks

Michael